# How to make MatLab to write a txt with a list of files and their durations?

Tags: matlab, list, file, wav, duration

I have a folder containing several wav files and wanted to make MatLab to go through all of them and write their duration on a txt file. Anyone has a clue how to do it?
I already know how to get the the duration for one single file:

```
[w,fs] = wavread('filename.wav');
length = length(w)/fs;
```

but I cannot figure out how to make the loop to read all files on a folder.

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You probably need `files=dir('*.wav')` to get all file names. Don't use the variable names like `length` which conflict with built-in functions. You can't use the function after creating such a variable.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this but something like this should help get you started or most of the way.

```
fid = fopen('durations.txt'); % File to save durations to
files = dir('*.wav'); % Creates a struct containing details of each file

for i = 1:length(files)
    [w,fs] = wavread(files(i).name); % files(i).name is the filename
    duration = length(w)/fs;
    fprintf(fid, 'File %s is %.4f seconds long\n', files(i).name, duration); % Writes one line to the file
end
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was going to write but I got called to a meeting lol. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Guess I'm lucky you had that meeting ;)

Comment: Come swing by our MATLAB and Octave chatroom if you like :) a lot of us convene there very often! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave